# Illuminate\Database\QueryException : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `users`

Tags: php, laravel

I have a question and the answers i have been getting are not really helping me.

So I have been trying to basically create a Profiles table for each users. I followed through the rules for One to One relationship but i keep getting this error

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`, `admin`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Darlington Okorie, darlingtonokoriec@gmail.com, $2y$10$Ob161LW8sbbv5uDv9VVbienlmW.DWXVDK3wdfC0I0NlnOrg1Jx/a2, 1, 2019-12-23 17:41:30, 2019-12-23 17:41:30))

Heres the code i wrote in my `UsersTableSeeder`

```
public function run()
{

 $user = App\User::create([
        'name' => 'Darlington Okorie',
        'email' => 'darlingtonokoriec@gmail.com',
        'password' => bcrypt('password'),
        'admin' => 1
    ]);

    App/Profile::create([
        'user_id' =>  $user->id,
        'avatar' => 'uploads/avatar/img.png',
        'about' => 'Great at writing. Better at blogging',
        'facebook' => 'facebook.com',
        'youtube' => 'youtube.com'
    ]);
}
```

And i had also defined `user_id` in my `create_users_table`

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('user_id');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->boolean('admin')->default(0);
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

And defined the `user_id` in my `create_profiles_table`

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('avatar');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->text('about');
        $table->string('facebook');
        $table->string('youtube');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Is `App/Profile` a typo or a copy/paste issue? Should be `App\Profile` (wrong slash direction).

Comment: Can you share your `User` model?

Comment: Just noticed that. Will check and confirm. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with your `users` migration, and not the `profiles` migration. Your migration has this line:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
  ...
  $table->string('user_id'); // This one
```

Which is creating a non-null `varchar` column called `user_id`. In your `Seed` file, **you're not setting that**, and `null` is not allowed. Add and configure the following line below:

```
 $user = App\User::create([
  'name' => 'Darlington Okorie',
  'email' => 'darlingtonokoriec@gmail.com',
  'password' => bcrypt('password'),
  'admin' => 1,
  'user_id' => 'SomeRandomString' // Add this, set to whatever is logical.
]);
```

Alternatively, set `nullable()` on your `users` migration:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->string('user_id')->nullable();
```

Honestly, unless you need a separate identifier for each `User`, your `users` table likely doesn't need a `user_id`, and you can remove it from the migration completely.

Edit: I'm really not sure who downvoted, but read the error message:

> Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into **users** ...)

When this error is encountered, the query is trying to insert into the **`users`** table, not the `profiles` one. Since `users.user_id` doesn't have a default value, nor does it allow `null`, the error is being thrown. The 3 alternatives above provide a solution to this.

The error has nothing to do with the `User` or `Profile` models, as there is an issue with the migration itself.

Answer (score 5):

I faced this kind of issue as well.
My Case, I forgot to write the field in `fillable`.

```
protected $fillable = [
        'name', 
    ];
```

After writing the field in $fillable. My Issue was solved.

Comment: Absolutely and it took a precious time from me, just because of the way they created the models for Laravel. It is very inefficient and issues prone. When you scaffold a model/controller all the properties should be included by default, so that the developer can choose which ones to remove, if any, but adding them is much easier to forget to do.

Answer (score 0):

> General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value

what this error is saying is that you have a column in the table that you didn't pass

a value for in your form...In your case you didn't pass a value for the field

user_id.I guess what you are trying to implement is that you want to give the primary

key a name.so the fix should be to rename the column $table->bigIncrements('id'); to

$table->bigIncrements('user_id'); and delete the   $table->string('user_id');

Answer (score 0):

You can set 'user_id' to allow null from db.

Comment: Suggesting an alteration to the database definition really should come with some explanation of what the impact of doing so might be. Also please don't format regular text as code.

Answer (score -1):

I don't how your relationship is set up but try to make some changes as mentioned below. REMOVE THE use_id from users table. You don't need that column. Or Just rename it to USER_CODE for example make it nullable if it is not a mandatory column  `$table->string('user_id')->nullable();`
To be honest I don't see the purpose of having user_id column in usrs table

```
// Profiles Migration:    

public function up()
{
Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
    ...
    $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
     ....
   $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
            ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
  });
}

// Profile.php Model
public function user()  

{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

// User.php Model
public function user()
  {
      return $this->hasOne('App\Profile');
  }

// Inside your Controller

   $user = new App\User;
   $user->name = 'Darlington Okorie';
   $user->email = 'darlingtonokoriec@gmail.com';
   $user->password = bcrypt('password');
   $user->admin => 1;
   if($user->save()) {

     $userID = $user->id;

     $profile = new App/Profile;
     $profile->user_id =  $userID;
     $profile->avatar = 'uploads/avatar/img.png';
     $profile->about = 'Great at writing. Better at blogging';
     $profile->facebook = 'facebook.com';
     $profile->youtube = 'youtube.com';
     $profile->save();
    }
```